# Replicating the values to another textbox

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding JSP. I have two textboxes. When I type the value in the first text box, it should replicate automatically in the second text box.

```
<input type="text" 
       class="formtext" 
       name="List.lItemList<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>.value1" 
       value="0.0"
       onChange="validateOnChange(this,'desc','minvalue','maxValue','float')">
<input type="text" 
       class="formtext" 
       name="List.clItemList<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>.value2" 
       value="0.0" 
       onChange="validateOnChange(this,'desc','minvalue','maxvalue','float')">
```

Comment: Might wanna put the code in a code sample :D

Comment: <input type="text" class="formtext" name="List.clItemList<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>.value1" value="0.0" onChange="validateOnChange(this,'desc','minvalue','maxValue','float')"> <input type="text" class="formtext" name="List.clItemList<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>.value2" value="0.0" onChange="validateOnChange(this,'Desc','minValue','maxvalue','float')">

Comment: I mean the code span/code sample http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Im not really that good with javascript but is it possible to have the page change when it is already loaded without refreshing or redirecting the page? I know that with asp if you have 2 boxes and you give the 2nd box the value of the first one it will get that value once it has been posted not directly when typed in.

Comment: @Mythje: Yes, but ASP runs on the *server*, JavaScript (in this case) on the *client*.

Comment: That's why i said that i don't know about JavaScript. But in that case shouldn't it be easy? / shouldn't just assigning the fist textboxses value to the second work?

Comment: I have already used on change event here to track the value if it doesn't fall inside the min max value. using Getelementbyid to get the value for the first and assign it to second.does it help ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061489/jquery-duplicate-field-input-text-in-real-time

Comment: Is there any other way to do this..thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the first box has ID `input1` and the second `input2` (so you'll have to add those IDs), you can do it like this:

```
document.getElementById('input1').onkeyup = function () {
    document.getElementById('input2').value = this.value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JavaScript. Attach an keyup event handler on the first textbox which should copy its value to the second one.

```
<input type="text" id="t1" onkeyup="document.getElementById('t2').value=this.value" /> 
<input type="text" id="t2" />
```