# How to duplicate form field text input in another field simulaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve here is a client brief form, where our company manager can type in the clients name at the top in the quick glance section, and then it's replicated below under the client details section. Ideally i'd like it to replicate it out as he's typing.

I had a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061489/jquery-duplicate-field-input-text-in-real-time), and unfortunately it hasn't helped me. Then again it might be because my Jquery scripting is very poor.

So input in #client_name replicated in #client_name_output in real time is what I'm trying to achieve :)

Any help will be appreciated!

```
<fieldset>
    <legend><span class="number">1</span>At A Glance</legend>
    <label for="name">Manager</label> 

    <select id="manager" name="manager">
        <optgroup id="OTA" label="OTA">
            <option id="vernon_penny">Vernon Penny</option>
            <option id="nick_heygate">Glenn Collie</option>
            <option id="nick_heygate">Nick Heygate</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>

    <input type="text" id="client_name" name="client" placeholder="Client">
    <input type="text" id="project_name" name="project_name" placeholder="Project Name">
    <label for="date">Deadline</label>
    <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend><span class="number">2</span>Client Info</legend>
    <p id="client_name_output"></p>
    <input type="url" id="website" name="client_website" placeholder="Website">
    <textarea id="bio" name="client_bio" placeholder="bio"></textarea>
</fieldset>

    <button type="submit" class="large btn">Send</button>
```

Comment: Those are four lines of code in the linked question. It really cannot get any simpler than that. If you can't get it to work, then at least explain what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you want.The ideas is, you need to capture the `#client_name` value then assign it value into `#client_name_output`. Try this code, hopes it help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#client_name').on('keyup',function(){
     var c_val = $(this).val();
     $('#client_name_output').text(c_val);
 });
});
```

Comment: @JurgenVandw : The showing code is less writing and great. But, how about storing those value first in variable before putting into another placeholder. For me, it is maintainable. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to check if there is a keyup on the input. If so, just update the client_name_output.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#client_name').keyup(function () {
        $('#client_name_output').text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

The document.ready makes sure you wait till the DOM is being loaded before you bind a function on a non-existing id.

Make sure you have a reference to the jquery code in your html.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is no reason to search for `#client_name` again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $('#client_name').on('keyup', function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('#client_name_output').text(text);
  });
});
```

Would be the simplest way.

https://jsfiddle.net/jsj7nh6f/2/

Comment: I find `$('#client_name_output').text(this.value);` even simpler. Also, didn't you just post what Norlihazmey posted almost 20min earlier than you? Which value does your answer add to this question?